# "I would argue" - what does it mean in following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following paragraph, i don't get the meaning of the last part "I would argue, should you always feel you must." Any possible explanation will be appreciated.

> The truth is that the human mind is far more complex than any “secret.” And you can’t simply change yourself; nor, I would argue, should you always feel you must.

Comment: what is the source of this quote please? Additional context might help.

Answer (score 1):

In general when a person say or write "I would argue" it means that the person thinks that what s/he says is true, but does not claim that it is clearly proved. often the person offers reason -- arguments -- to support the view, but sometimes only implies that such arguments exist and could be brought forward. The implication is that the person making the statement would be prepared to defend the statement in some sort of debate, but that a differing view is legitimate enough that it could also be argued.

In the sentence:

> And you can’t simply change yourself; nor, I would argue, should you always feel you must.

the writer is saying that a person can't easily or automatically change himself or herself, **and** that a person should not always even feel some sort of need or obligation to make a change. The placement of the phrase "I would argue"  means that the writer is stating he fist part -- that a person cant just change easily -- as absolute fact. The second part, the writer is saying is more of an opinion, but the writer thinks that there are good reasons to support the opinion that a person need not feel a need to change.

It happens that I am rather fond of the phrase "I would argue" and use it with some frequency, so I have some experience in how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree that the use of the phrase necessarily implies, as @DavidSiegel claims, that 'the person...does not claim that it is clearly proved'. The expression can be used to express the following thought: ' I claim that X is true, but I do not wish to make the case forcefully and possibly upset somebody.'

In that context the phrase is being used out of politeness. The use of the apparently conditional phrasing is comparable to saying 'I would like a drink' when you really mean 'I want a drink'.